# Get Groups from User in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, users, php, user-groups

Wondering if I can get user `groups` directly after retrieving the user via `craft()->users->getUserById($id)`, or if i need to use `craft()->userGroups->getGroupsByUserId($id)` also?

As of right now, I'm looping through many users and want to check if they are in a specific group. A rough idea of what I'm looking at now:

```
// get user (necessary for rest of plugin)
$user = craft()->users->getUserById( $uid );

// get user groups
$user_groups = craft()->userGroups->getGroupsByUserId( $uid );

// check if user is in group
if( in_array("Group_Name", $user_groups) )
{
   // do something
}
```

This works, but when looping through a ton of users, I imagine it would be silly not to first check that I can already get this information from the `$user` variable I created. I can't seem to find the answer via documentation. Hoping to get a confirmation from someone!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code to get a user returns a `UserModel` (as can be seen from the [Full Class Reference docs](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/UsersService#getUserById-detail)):

```
$user = craft()->users->getUserById($id);
```

You can then get the user groups the `$user` is a member of using`getGroups()`([from the `UserModel` class)](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel#getGroups-detail):

```
$user_groups = $user->getGroups();
```