# Login test for user's group?

Tags: conditional, login

I want to display some content only if a user from a certain group (wholesalers) is currently logged-in. The following syntax seems to work - but is there something more shorthand than the nested conditionals I'm using?

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {% if currentUser.isInGroup('wholesalers') %}
        Do something here...
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Also, where do I find the group ID # for the user groups I've set-up?

Comment: You can find that by navigating to the group settings in the CP and looking at the URL. It will be something like `admin/settings/users/groups/4` the number is the group ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine your conditions like so:

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.isInGroup('wholesalers') %}
  Do something here...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thx @Luke Pearce

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement or an `if` statement using `getGroups()`.

Instead of me taking all the credit, [here is a great thread along with an example](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/how-do-you-display-a-users-user-group) of using `getGroups` at the template level.

Here is what that might look like [within a plugin](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/get-groups-from-user-in-plugin).

To get the actual ID of the group - I'm sure there is a more scientific way, but If I'm always going to know what the ID is, I'll just hover over the handle and look at the url. It will be something like `/settings/users/groups/2`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx @Damon. Saw that. It'll be useful when I need to pull some other info. If the Craft folks are watching this thread, there's a feature request here to surface this is the UI.